# Docker: is it possible not to build from scratch w/o using cache?

Tags: docker, docker-build

I had a simple Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements
```

The problem was - it installs requirements on every build. I have a lot of requirements, but they rarely change.

I searched for solutions and ended up with this:

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
```

That worked perfectly fine, till moment it stopped updating the code. E.g., comment couple lines in some file that goes to /app and build - lines stays uncommented in image.

I searched again and found out that this is possibly caused by cache. I tried ***--no-cache*** build flag, but now I'm getting requirements installation again.

Is there some workaround or right way to do it in my situation?

Comment: What commands are you using to build and run the image?  How are you seeing that your changes aren't having an effect?

Comment: I am not sure how pip works in this sense, but if it will only somehow download specific versions of dependencies, then you can pre-prepared them manually, in docker file just copy the content to requested location- if its independent - and additionally, you can still install some additional dep. which still needs from some reason be downloaded every build. Maybe? Eg. in comparison with maven, it will "just download some jars" , so you can download them manually and then copy. So you can change just a little layer of image.

Comment: @DavidMaze Scenario to see files unchanged: 1) docker build -t <name> . 2) docker run --rm -ti <name> bash 3) cat /app/filename

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx gues that could be the workaround taking in account SiHa's answer

Comment: @Mikekekeke I dont think so, in requirements file I found you need also to specify versions in static way, so basically, its a static content (in sense of versions), so well, you can deliver them manually, by copy. In this sense of docker, it can work with cache, so you dont need to rebuild all layers everytime, but only layer which was changed. If you do not change the layer with copy, then it should be built faster I assume :) In theory at least..

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ADD` not `COPY` if you want to invalidate cache.

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /app
```

Try the above docker file.

Comment: `ADD` and `COPY` are identical as regards [the build cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/#leverage-build-cache).  The only differences are that `ADD` will perform HTTP GETs and unpack archives on its own.  Usually you should prefer `COPY` unless you specifically want that behavior.

Comment: You are right reading the docs again sure seems to say that. Let me go try an experiment

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever used docker-compose? Docker-compose has 'volumes', it's as a cache, and when you start container, It will not re-build your dependencies. It auto refresh when your code changes.
and with your situation, you should do like this:

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD["python","app.py"]
```

Let try.

Comment: Current workflow in project I'm working on doesn't include docker-compose. Now its just "build image -> deploy to kubernetes cluster"

Comment: you did it? you should build image and push onto docker hub by command: docker build --tag your_acc/image:tag and then "tag" and push on docker hub. then use it with kubernetes

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing. But I can check whether or not files in image up to date w/o pushing them to hub. I didn't try your suggested docker file yet, tho

Comment: you can access container by command:" docker run -it your_image bash" to check your file.

Answer (score 1):

Changing a file that you simply copy in (`COPY . /app`) will not be seen by Docker, so it will use a cached layer *, hence your result. Using `--no-cache` will force a re-build of every layer, again explaining what you've observed.

The 'docker' way to avoid re-installing all requirements every time would be to put all the static requirements in a base image, then use this image in your `FROM` line with all the other requirements which do change.

---

<sub><sub>* Although, I'm fairly sure I've observed that if you copy a named file, as opposed to a directory, changes are picked up even without `--no-cache`</sub></sub>

Comment: The actual contents of the files are supposed to be used to decide whether to use [the cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/#leverage-build-cache) or not (see the third bullet point).